# How to do arithmetic calculation in Action listener

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm supposed to make a gui that allows people to order food by inputting the amount of food they want to order and then display the total price of the item.
However my line of code that helps calculate the cost of the meal has an error saying "*" operator is undefined. Also is my .getText() used properly? How do I fix it? Feel free to help point out other areas that I can improve in my coding.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class LunchGUI implements ActionListener {

static JFrame frame;
static JPanel topPanel,panel;   
static JLabel adult,kid,salad,dessert,price;
static JTextField adultq,kidq,saladq,dessertq;
static JButton confirm;

public static void main(String []args) {

    Font font = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD,24);
    Color Color = new Color(249,206,188);

    frame = new JFrame("Lunch Menu");
    //define a new layout
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //panel for label 
    topPanel = new JPanel();
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color);
    topPanel.setBackground(Color);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2, 0, 20));
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
    panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);     

    adult = new JLabel("  Adult Lunch Set $20 Quantity :");            
    adult.setFont(font);
    adult.setBackground(java.awt.Color.CYAN);
    adult.setOpaque(true);

    adultq = new JTextField ("0");
    adultq.setFont(font);
    adultq.setBackground(java.awt.Color.CYAN);
    adultq.setOpaque(true);

    kid = new JLabel("  Kids Lunch Set $12  Quantity :");            
    kid.setFont(font);
    kid.setBackground(java.awt.Color.CYAN);
    kid.setOpaque(true);

    kidq = new JTextField ("0");
    kidq.setFont(font);
    kidq.setBackground(java.awt.Color.CYAN);
    kidq.setOpaque(true);

    salad = new JLabel("  Salad Side $4       Quantity :");            
    salad.setFont(font);
    salad.setBackground(java.awt.Color.CYAN);
    salad.setOpaque(true);

    saladq = new JTextField ("0");
    saladq.setFont(font);
    saladq.setBackground(java.awt.Color.CYAN);
    saladq.setOpaque(true);

    dessert = new JLabel("  Dessert $5          Quantity :");            
    dessert.setFont(font);
    dessert.setBackground(java.awt.Color.CYAN);
    dessert.setOpaque(true);

    dessertq = new JTextField ("0");
    dessertq.setFont(font);
    dessertq.setBackground(java.awt.Color.CYAN);
    dessertq.setOpaque(true);

    confirm = new JButton("Confirm");            
    confirm.setFont(font);
    confirm.setBackground(java.awt.Color.CYAN);
    confirm.setOpaque(true);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("What would you like to order?");
    label.setFont(font);

    JLabel price = new JLabel("2323");
    price.setFont(font);
    price.setBackground(Color);
    price.setOpaque(true);

    panel.add(adult);
    panel.add(adultq);
    panel.add(kid);
    panel.add(kidq);
    panel.add(salad);
    panel.add(saladq);
    panel.add(dessert);
    panel.add(dessertq);
    panel.add(confirm);     
    panel.add(price);

    topPanel.add(label);
    topPanel.setSize(200, 30);
    //rearrange panels on frame
    frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setSize(1000, 800);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    confirm.addActionListener(new LunchGUI());
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String adultamt = adultq.getText();
    String kidamt = kidq.getText();
    String saladamt = saladq.getText();
    String dessertamt = dessertq.getText();
    String total = (20*adultamt)+(14*kidamt)+(4*saladamt)+(5*dessertamt);
    price.setText(total);

}


}
```

Comment: You're trying to multiply a string. Try multiplying a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, that you are trying to calculate the total using strings, this won't work. In Java you can only do these arithmetic calculations with fixed arithmetic data types (e.g. int, double, ...). So what you need to do before your calculation is to parse the strings you retrieved by `.getText()` into an int value for example.

```
int adultamt = Integer.parseInt(adultq.getText());
```

Then calculate the total and parse this back to a String.

```
int total = (20 * adultamt) + ....;
price.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! However for the line price.setText(total.toString()); an error showed saying cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type int. What can i do to fix it? Sorry for the trouble as I am still new to programming.

Comment: That was my bad, I updated the response to fix it. Use String.valueOf(total) to get the correct string representation of the integer.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have anymore questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks and apparently I am now facing a new runtime error stating that there is an Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException. How do I fix it and make the program function properly?

Comment: A NullPointerException means that you tried to access an Object, but the accessed field was null. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html To find out what caused the error, you need to look deeper into the Exception, which should point you to the position where the error happened.

Comment: I've read and tried to understand but I still dont understand why the numbers i input in the textfield is considered as null? How do I make it read it as an object for the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

You can't multiply the string value. You need to change the data type like this:

```
int adultamt = Integer.parseInt(adultq.getText());
.
.
int dessertamt = Integer.parseInt(dessertq.getText());

int total = adult + .. + dessertamt;

price.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! However for the line price.setText(total.toString()); an error showed saying cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type int. What can i do to fix it? Sorry for the trouble as I am still new to programming.

Comment: My bad. 
String.valueOf(total) instead of toString()